# Deleting "weak homeomorphism" in a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

It is well-known that there exists a homeomorphism $h$
from an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ to $H\setminus\{0\}$.
Does there exist a "weak homeomorphism" $g:H \to H\setminus\{0\}$,
that is, $g$ is bijective, and $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are weakly continuous?

Comment: I don't get it: doesn't strong continuity imply weak continuity? so your $g$ could be your previous $h$?

Comment: Use the same topology on both ends.  Then strong continuity need not imply weak continuity.

Comment: same quesion on MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421450/deleting-weak-homeomorphism-in-a-hilbert-space